# unable to add ng2-materialize to github.com/angular/quickstart

Tags: angular, materialize

I tried to add github.com/sherweb/ng2-materialize to  github.com/angular/quickstart  with below changes

```
"materialize-css": "",
"mdi": "",
"jQuery": "",
"ng2-materialize": "",
//in Package.json 'dependencies' and 'devDependencies'
```

[systemjs.config.js Image, code below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2xBO.png)

```
  'jquery':                    'npm:jquery',
  'materialize-css':           'npm:materialize-css',
  'mdi':                       'npm:mdi',
  'ng2-materialize':           'npm:ng2-materialize',
```

Please check component and module [image here, code below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqopR.jpg) for component and module

component

```
import { MaterializeModule } from 'ng2-materialize';
```

module

```
@Component({   selector: 'my-app',   template: `
             <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
             <div class="card-panel teal lighten-2">This is a card panel with a teal lighten-2 class</div>
            `, }) export class AppComponent  { name = 'Angular'; }
```

but i am getting the error and itsnot loading

```
[0] 1:10:56 PM - Compilation complete. Watching for file changes
[1] 17.02.26 13:10:57 200 GET /main.js
[1] 17.02.26 13:10:57 304 GET /@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js
[1] 17.02.26 13:10:57 200 GET /app/app.module.js
[1] 17.02.26 13:10:57 304 GET /@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js
[1] 17.02.26 13:10:57 304 GET /@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js
[1] 17.02.26 13:10:57 304 GET /@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js
[1] 17.02.26 13:10:57 200 GET /app/app.component.js
........
[1] 17.02.26 13:10:57 404 GET /node_modules/ng2-materialize/
```

Without materialize its loading correctly, its not picking up the external materialize design modules only , its also doing NPM start - no error there except the above

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. As workaround you can use the following code

File: systemjs.config.js

```
var packages = {
    ...
    'ng2-materialize': {
        main: 'dist/index.js'
    }
    ...
};

var paths = {
    'npm:': 'node_modules/'
};

map = {
...
    'ng2-materialize': 'npm:ng2-materialize'
...
}

var ngMaterializePackageNames = [
        'button',
        'card',
        'checkbox',
        'collapsible',
        'dropdown',
        'input',
        'navbar',
        'parallax',
        'progress',
        'radio-button',
        'icon',
        'select',

        'sidenav',
        'sidenav/sidenav-collapsible',
        'sidenav/sidenav-divider',
        'sidenav/sidenav-header',
        'sidenav/sidenav-link',
        'sidenav/sidenav-subheader',

        'spinner',
        'textarea',
        'tooltip',

        'toast',
        'toast/services'
  ];

 function packMaterialize(pkgName) {
        packages['ng2-materialize/dist/'+pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }

ngMaterializePackageNames.forEach(packMaterialize);

var config = {
        map: map,
        paths: paths,
        packages: packages
 };

System.config(config);
```

Comment: Sergey what does it do ... is it one time import or component level import

Comment: It's one time import in your $PROJECT_DIR/src/systemjs.config.js file.

Comment: Thanks Sergey .. i was confused trying to import it everywhere. Thanks a lot.